# Check if a checkbox is checked or not using Selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following code snippet represents a `checkbox` and I want to check whether it is checked or not using Selenium.

```
for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
{
    List<WebElement> td1 = row1.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    WebElement check = td1.get(j);

    if (check.isEnabled())
    {
        if (!check.isSelected())
        {
            List<WebElement> checkBox = ele
                    .findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@ng-change,'vm.updateInvoicingMethodMailByGroup(item)')]"));
            WebElement elem3 = checkBox.get(count);
            elem3.click();
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I check this, the class changes from

```
class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-empty ng-touched"
```

to

```
class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-not-empty ng-touched"
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="invoicingByMailFlag" ng-model="item.invoicingByMailFlag"
    ng-change="vm.updateInvoicingMethodMailByGroup(item)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty
    ng-valid-parse ng-empty ng-touched">`
```

Comment: what do you mean `isSelected()` is not working ? are you getting any error?

Comment: No, It's not throwing any error. It enters into the loop even though it is checked.

Comment: can you post the relevant code

Comment: for(int j=2;j<5;j++){
    List<WebElement> td1 = row1.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    WebElement check = td1.get(j);
    if(check.isEnabled()){
     if(!check.isSelected()){
      List<WebElement> checkBox = ele.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@ng-change,'vm.updateInvoicingMethodMailByGroup(item)')]"));
      WebElement elem3 = checkBox.get(count);
      elem3.click();
      count++;
      break;
     }
     
    }
   }

Comment: added the code.

Comment: @K.Krishnakanth Whenever you have additional information that is useful or necessary to understanding the question (e.g. the code you just posted in a comment), please edit the question and add it there, properly formatted. This helps other readers see all the relevant info without having to read all the comments to get the full story. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it has class attribute `ng-empty` or not

```
List<WebElement> checkBoxes = ele.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@ng-change,'vm.u‌​pdateInvoicingMethod‌​MailByGroup(item)')]‌​"));
WebElement checkBox = checkBoxes.get(count);
if (checkBox.getAttribute("class").contains("ng-empty")) {
    // checkbox not checked
}
```

Comment: @K.Krishnakanth If this answer (or any answer) is useful, please upvote it. If the answer worked for you, please accept it.

Comment: I upvoted it but it is not accepting because I have less reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement to check the unchecked boxes then try below code :

```
List <WebElement> allcheckbox =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));

for(WebElement element : allcheckbox)
{
    if(!(element.isSelected()))
    {
        element.click();
    }
}
```